# Modifying the inproceedings style in a Latex bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, custom-bib

I am using `makebst` to create my own customised bibliography style `mycustomisedbiblio.bst`, and sometimes modifying the `mycustomisedbiblio.dbj` file to change further settings. Below is an example on how an `@inproceedings` type of reference would appear with this style:

[image: 1]]

**I would like to replace the quotation marks by italic, while keeping the ''*in*''**. I have been looking at the `.dbj` file, however it only allows you to include or not the quotes for an inproceedings type of reference, but it does not allow you to put the title in italic. I am not familiar with the `.bst` coding language so I have not tried to modify the `mycustomisedbiblio.bst` file.

Does anyone know how I could put the inproceedings name in italic?

Comment: With just the information given, it is impossible to give an answer that will help you. So, please clarify: The string `In` should stay as it is, the title should be italic instead of having quotes around?

Comment: Yes, "Proceedings [...] 1997" should be in italic and the In as it is.

Comment: Please edit the question to bump the question back on the top of the question stack. more people will see it. But without more details about the bibstyle, an answer needs to be written by an extremely familiar person with makebst, which is *a psychich*. More information are needed.